# Maintain Markup Format with Highlight.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, highlight.js

I am attempting to display dynamically generated HTML on my web page and do highlighting/formatting using `highlight.js`. I have the highlighting working correctly, however the indentation is not correct. Here's the [**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/clovola/oz13webx/).

The code shows like this:
 `<div class="parent">parentContent<div class="child">childContent</div><div class="child">childContent</div><div class="child">childContent</div></div>`

whereas I'd like to show up as it would in an IDE:

```
<div class="parent">
    parentContent
   <div class="child">
       childContent
   </div>
   <div class="child">
       childContent
   </div>
   <div class="child">
       childContent
   </div>
</div>
```

I understand it's called `highlight.js` not `format.js` :) but I thought it was possible and I haven't had much luck getting an answer from the [**API**](http://highlightjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#fixmarkup-value). I have tried configuring line breaks via             `hljs.configure({ useBR: true });` and the [fixMarkup('value')](http://highlightjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#fixmarkup-value) looked promising but I have not implemented it with any success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hear me out. I know this might seem kludgey, but you can put your html together as a string, like so:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    var html = '<div class="parent">' +
        '\n\tparentContent';

    for ( var j = 0; j < 3; j++){
        html += '\n\t<div class="child">childContent</div>';
    }

    html += '\n</div>\n'

    $('.grid-container')[0].innerHTML += html;
}
```

This gives you full control of the white space. It's also *probably faster* because you're not appending to the DOM several times, just once. You only trigger a redraw one time when you set the `innerHTML` of `.grid-container`.

JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/dgrundel/fjLwa592/1/

Comment: I hadn't considered manually adding the tabs, it works for my purposes thank you.

Comment: You know what they say, "when you want something done right...". :)